# How to import an ECMAScript module, then pause code execution until all code in the module has been executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

In my main JavaScript file I've imported an ECMASCript module (a separate file named `module.js`).  In the main file, is there any way to import the module, then pause execution of of the main file until all code in the module has been executed, then resume execution of the remaining lines in `main.js`?

---

**My Code**

***main.js***

```
import { hello } from './module.js';
console.log(hello());
console.log('Print this after Hello World.');
```

***module.js***

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';// Needed in order to use fetch() in Node.

export function hello() {

  fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return 'Hello World!';
  });

}
```

**Desired Output**

```
Hello World!
Print this after Hello World.
```

**Actual Output**

```
undefined
Print this after Hello World.
```

**Attempted Solution:  promise**

If I try to wrap the `import` and `console.log()` lines in a promise, I encounter a JS console error saying `import` must be in the top level of a file only.

*edit: It seems like I could perhaps wrap `hello()` in a promise, and use a `then` to execute code after the promise is resolved?*

**Possible Solution:  async/await**

Could I use async/await in `main.js` to ensure script execution paused until the code in the module was complete?  The `import` line would remain in the top level of the file, correct?

Thanks.

Comment: `(async () => { await hello(); console.log('hello'); })();`

Comment: @Adam Thanks for that.  Unfortunately I may need a couple days to test.  I'll be sure to report back here.